# Rails: How to query based on an extra field in a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, associations

I am intrigued on how I could query a many-to-many relationship based on an extra field present in the join table. Best asked via an example.

I have a model **User**, and a model **Group**.

The many-to-many relationship is called **Groupization**. It has an extra field **'active_user'**. I would like to query for all the users in a group that are active.

If I do:

`@user.groupizations.find_all_by_active_user(true)` - gives me a list of groupizations; however, I would be looking for a list of users. Maybe I would need to do some mapping?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by joining the association to the query, and then searching in the scope of the associated table:

```
User.joins(:groupizations).where(:groupizations => {:active_user => true})
```

Note that this will return duplicate rows if multiple groupizations meet this criteria.  To get distinct users you can do one of the following:

- Add a call to `.select("DISTINCT users.*")` with some ORDER clause as `.order("users.id")` (change the sort column as needed)
- Add a GROUP BY clause like this: `.group("users.id")`.  For non-MySQL databases, you may need to be more specific and include all columns in the grouping:

  `.group(User.column_names.map{|c| "users.#{c}"}.join(','))`

Answer (score 0):

With an extra field on the join table you should use has_many :through instead of has_many_to_many. It does more with the same API

```
class User
  has_many :groupizations
  has_many :groups, through: groupization

  scope :active, joins(:groupizations).where("groupizations.active_user='1'")
end

# controller
@active_users = User.active
```

Comment: interesting. i dont think it is completely right - gives me [] ... not sure where the error is. assuming it worked, how could i look for the active users for a particular group?

Comment: I get the following sql query: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "groupizations" ON "groupizations"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHER
E (groupizations.active_user='1')

Comment: I was assuming you were on mysql where booleans are ints, but it really should be: where(:groupizations => {:active_user => true}) which will generate the right query according to your db (postgres...)